# Apostol's Calculus: optimize the perimeter of isosceles triangle inscribed in circle

Tags: calculus, optimization

As much as I hate to ask for a hint on this, I've gotta admit--I'm stuck. None of my previous attempts to solve this were successful, and I can't think of a fresh way to look at the problem.

This is from Apostol's *Calculus,* Volume 1.

The following problem and the accompanying picture are on page 195.

> An isosceles triangle is inscribed in a circle of radius r. If the angle $2\alpha$ at the apex is restricted to lie between $0$ and $\frac {\pi}{2},$ find the largest value and the smallest value of the perimeter of the triangle. Give full details of your reasoning.

Here's a brief description of the picture: An isosceles triangle is inscribed in a circle. The diameter is drawn and bisects the triangle. At one end of the diameter is the base: a chord perpendicular to the diameter. At the other end is the apex of the triangle (again, bisected by the diameter), which touches the circle.

Let $C$ be the center of the circle. Draw a radius from $C$ to either vertex at the base. This radius will form an angle $\theta=2\alpha$ with the diameter. Since the diameter bisects the triangle, it suffices to minimize or maximize either half of the perimeter of the triangle. Half of base is then $r\sin 2\alpha$. Using the law of cosines and the trig identity $\cos (x- \frac{\pi}{2})=\sin(x)$, either leg will have length $$\sqrt {2r^2-2r^2\mathrm {sin}2\alpha},$$ so that the perimeter of half the triangle is $$P(x)=r\sin 2\alpha+\sqrt{2r^2-2r^2 \mathrm {sin}2\alpha}.$$ Differentiating gives you $$P'(x)=2r\cos2\alpha - \frac{2r^2\cos 2\alpha}{\sqrt{2r^2-2r^2 \mathrm {sin}2\alpha}}.$$ At that point, I think, "This can't be right. I supposed to set *that* equal to $0$ and solve? That can't be right."

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Why not set that equal to $0$ and solve?  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Half the base is indeed $r\sin 2\alpha$. We now find  the length of one of the other sides of the triangle. By trigonometry this is $\dfrac{r\sin 2\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$, which is $2r\cos\alpha$.

So we want to maximize/minimize $r\sin 2\alpha +2r\cos\alpha$. We can forget about $2r$, and only worry about $\sin\alpha\cos\alpha +\cos\alpha$.

Examining the derivative of this should not be difficult. We get a quadratic in $\sin\alpha$. It even factors nicely.

Comment: I can't see how the length of either leg is $\frac {r \mathrm{sin}2\alpha}{\mathrm {sin} \alpha}$.

Comment: You have drawn the diagram. So you have have split the triangle into two halves, each right-angled. The angle at the top of each is $\alpha$. So if $x$ is the length of the remaining side, then $\frac{r\sin 2\alpha}{x}=\sin \alpha$. Solve for $x$.

Comment: Aha! Thanks so much Andre!

Comment: You are welcome.